# Library in Python similar to PHPEXCEL library

Tags: python, excel-formula, phpexcel

I need to use Excel's PRICE function in my python code. I searched but only found the [PHPEXCEL library to build this function](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Calculation/Financial.php#L1649), but in python I couldn't find it.

I tried to convert the PRICE function in PHPEXCEL to python but it is built from many different functions. I don't know too much about PHP, hope everyone can help me find a library in Python similar to the PHPEXCEL library!

Comment: just an idea how to implement in pandas https://www.trymito.io/excel-to-python/functions/financial/PRICE